# QR Code generation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, computer-vision, barcode, qr-code

Is there a .NET API that generates [QR Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) such as this one?

[image: Meagre human needs a phone to read QR codes. Ha ha ha.]

I'd like to display these on pages that I expect my users to print out.

Comment: QR code reads: "Meagre human needs a phone to read QR codes. Ha ha ha." Lovely. :)

Comment: I don't know why this was set as off-topic. I find it to be exactly on topic... :/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I wrote a basic HTML helper method to emit the correct `<img>` tag to take advantage of Google's API.  So, on your page (assuming ASPX view engine) use something like this:

```
<%: Html.QRCodeImage(Request.Url.AbsolutePath) %>
<%: Html.QRCodeImage("Meagre human needs a phone to read QR codes. Ha ha ha.") %>
```

Or if you want to specify the size in pixels (the image is always square):

```
<%: Html.QRCodeImage(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, size: 92) %>
```

Here is the code:

```
public static class QRCodeHtmlHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Produces the markup for an image element that displays a QR Code image, as provided by Google's chart API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="data">The data to be encoded, as a string.</param>
    /// <param name="size">The square length of the resulting image, in pixels.</param>
    /// <param name="margin">The width of the border that surrounds the image, measured in rows (not pixels).</param>
    /// <param name="errorCorrectionLevel">The amount of error correction to build into the image.  Higher error correction comes at the expense of reduced space for data.</param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">Optional HTML attributes to include on the image element.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString QRCode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string data, int size = 80, int margin = 4, QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel errorCorrectionLevel = QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel.Low, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        if (data == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (size < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size", size, "Must be greater than zero.");
        if (margin < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("margin", margin, "Must be greater than or equal to zero.");
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel), errorCorrectionLevel))
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("errorCorrectionLevel", (int)errorCorrectionLevel, typeof (QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel));

        var url = string.Format("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chld={2}|{3}&chs={0}x{0}&chl={1}", size, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data), errorCorrectionLevel.ToString()[0], margin);

        var tag = new TagBuilder("img");
        if (htmlAttributes != null)
            tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        tag.Attributes.Add("src", url);
        tag.Attributes.Add("width", size.ToString());
        tag.Attributes.Add("height", size.ToString());

        return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}

public enum QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel
{
    /// <summary>Recovers from up to 7% erroneous data.</summary>
    Low,
    /// <summary>Recovers from up to 15% erroneous data.</summary>
    Medium,
    /// <summary>Recovers from up to 25% erroneous data.</summary>
    QuiteGood,
    /// <summary>Recovers from up to 30% erroneous data.</summary>
    High
}
```

Comment: +1 for the funny sample string

Comment: +1 for exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Be aware that according this developers.google.com/chart/infographics Google Chart QR Code is deprecated

Answer (score 28):

One option is to use the [Google Chart Server API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes) to do it.

For instance, here's the QR code for this very page...

[image]

No code required :)

There are more details in the linked documentation, but you start with a URL of https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?, then add query parameters of:

- `cht=qr`: Specify that you want a QR code
- `chs=`*size*: Specify the size, e.g. `200x200`
- `chl=`*data*: Specify the data, e.g. a URL

There are other query parameters for output encoding and error correction.

Comment: Thanks.  I found this API shortly after posting and wrapped it up with an ASP.NET MVC helper method, as I'm going to call it from a bunch of places.  The code is posted in an answer, in case it helps someone else.

Comment: quick url update: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html

Comment: Be aware that according this https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/ Google Chart QR Code is deprecated

Comment: broken link, that's why its a bad practice to just put a link as an answer.

Comment: @sairfan: Well it wasn't *just* a link - it was also an example. I've updated the link and added some more details though.

Answer (score 7):

A quick search yields many QRCode libraries (all of them commercial except the first one):

- http://www.twit88.com/platform/projects/show/mt-qrcode (previously [here](http://www.twit88.com/home/opensource/qrcode))
- http://www.barcodelib.com/net_barcode/barcode_symbologies/qrcode.html
- http://www.businessrefinery.com/products/barcode_net/barcodes/net-qr-code.html
- http://www.componentsource.com/products/dbarcode-net-qr-code/index.html
- http://www.onbarcode.com/products/net_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html

Comment: Thanks.  The first link looks interesting.  By the way, that link is out of date (I'll edit your answer.)

Comment: Also you can use from the bellow products:

https://downloaddevtools.com/en/product/169/download-aspose-barcode-for-dotnet-with-license-key

https://downloaddevtools.com/en/product/2319/download-bytescout-barcode-generator-sdk

https://downloaddevtools.com/en/product/3235/download-tec-it-barcode-studio

Answer (score 5):

You might also consider the "Open Source QRCode Library on code project"

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is also a Nuget package available - [QRCodeHelper](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/QRCodeHelper) that's based on the Codeplex [QRCode Helper](http://qrcodehelper.codeplex.com/) project.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com

Comment: FYI, it's not strong-named

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple REST web service:

- [Library at CodePlex](http://qrcodeapi.codeplex.com/)
- [Documentation](http://www.esponce.com/help/api-v3/generate)

Example

http://www.esponce.com/api/v3/generate?content=Meagre+human+needs+a+phone+to+read+QR+codes.+Ha+ha+ha.&size=200x200